# Retrieve Access token from Accounts Manager

Tags: android, access-token, accountmanager, authenticator

I have implemented my own authenticator for Facebook and stored `access_token` in Accounts Manager.

I have tried all 3 ways to retrieve `auth_token`, but in vain.

In my method, I have started a thread, and in the `Threads RUN` method, I have tried foll ways:-

```
authTokenBundle = accountManagerFuture.getResult();

manager.blockingGetAuthToken(accounts[0], "com.facebook", false);
```

& the way u showed above...

```
manager.getAuthToken(account, "com.facebook", true, new AccountManagerCallback() {...
```

But my code gets blocked on all above 3 lines. No exception/error.

I need to get the `auth-token` in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the applications [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store and retreive the token.

My implementation:

```
    private String getTokenFromSharedPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences();
        return settings.getString(TOKEN, null);
    }

    private String getTokenSecretFromSharedPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences();
        return settings.getString(TOKEN_SECRET, null);
    }

    public void setTokenInSharedPreferences(String token){
        putInSharedPreferences(TOKEN, token);
    }

    public void setTokenSecretInSharedPreferences(String tokenSecret){
        putInSharedPreferences(TOKEN_SECRET, tokenSecret);
    }

    public void putInSharedPreferences(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences().edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    protected SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(){
        return activity.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, 0); //0 = MODE_PRIVATE.
    }
```